# Why were the disciples so concerned about their status within the group?

Tags: christian-living, gospels, pride

Why did the disciples, and the mother of James and John, seem so concerned about their status within the group of disciples? eg Mark 9 - but others too.

I am wondering if there is more to this than pride - which is surely part of the answer. However, though as adults we are definitely concerned about our status, arguments between adults about 'I am greater than you' are far from common - in my experience.

Is there some detail about the rabbi-disciple relationship here that is missed by a simple discussion of pride? Was there something at stake that is  more significant than just 'I am better than you'?

Comment: The assessment of personal motivation is, unavoidably, a matter of opinion. It is noticeable that scriptural authors very rarely (as in John 12:43) make such assessments. Jesus' action makes it irrelevant as to the motivation. _Anyone_ desiring greatness shall be the least, whatever the motivation. Voted to close as matter of opinion.

Comment: To avoid this Q being seen as inviting opinion, you may want to provide an objective criteria for the answer, such as asking in terms of NT background understanding of the kingdom or eschatological expectations of 1st century Jews.  Yes,I do think there is something more at stake than simple "I am greater than you".  +1

Comment: The other passage is Matt 20:20-28.

Comment: Could this be answered better on https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: OK - well, its my first post here so apologies if this is on the wrong board.